# Summarizing Only Rows with given criteria

Tags: t-sql

all!
Given the following table structure

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    idProduct INT, 
    Layers INT, 
    LayersOnPallet INT, 
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    Summarized BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
)
```

and the following insert statement which generates test data

```
INSERT INTO @TempTable(idProduct, Layers, LayersOnPallet)
SELECT 1, 2, 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 4
```

I would like to summarize only those rows (by the Layers only) with the same idProduct and which will have the sum of layers equal to LayersOnPallet.

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

From the picture above, you can see that only the first to rows were summarized because both have the same idProduct and the sum(layers) will be equal to LayersOnPallet.
How can I achieve this? It's there any way to do this only in selects (not with while)?

Thank you!

Comment: this part is not clear "rows with the same idProduct and which will have the sum of layers equal to LayersOnPallet."

Comment: Thank you for your response! I want to sum only the first 2 rows becase both have the same idProduct and the sum (4) will be equal to LayersOnPallet (4).

Comment: Sum of layers (2+2) != Sum of LayersOnPallet (4+4). How were they summarized?

Comment: Does layersOnPallet value never change?

Comment: The LayersOnPallet is the number of layers of a product which will fit a pallet so it's an attribute of the product.

Comment: There is some problem in your requirement. What if there are multiple combination of Layers' values that sums up to LayersOnPallet value?

Comment: Good question. I don't see a way to do this in one select, so I think the answer is no (It's there any way to do this only with selects (not with while)). I will use a while. Thank you again!

Comment: You can use CTE to achieve this without using while loop.

Comment: How I can use a CTE to achieve this without using while loop?

Comment: You could use recursion with CTE and do this, provided you have a clarity as to how you are gonna handle multiple combinations of layers whose sum  matches with your target column.

Comment: The priority would be first row to sum. I think would be necessary a row by procession in a recursion way trying to better fill a pallet. Will also exist the need to sum more than 2 rows to get a full pallet (maybe 2 + 1 + 1). I am thinking at backtracking but I am just asking if this could be done easier and how.

Comment: @Alex  What does your source data look like?  It seems you have got halfway through a solution and are now asking for advice, which could well be hampering progress.  If you can post your source data and desired result or overall purpose of the query you will probably get a better result.

Comment: The source data is like this: I have a few orders from different customers containing quantities for one or more products (boxes of water). The problem is that sometimes the customers order not a full pallet, but a fraction. These fractions have to be grouped so it you use as less pallets as it is possible. The full algorithm has almost 2000 lines so I cannot share it with you and it's not necessary also, but at the end results a table variable which looks like the one from the question. Each line from that table means someone has to go in the warehouse and pick the product-even it'sFullPallet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will do the trick. Note my comments:

```
-- your sample data
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    idProduct INT, 
    Layers INT, 
    LayersOnPallet INT, 
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    Summarized BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(idProduct, Layers, LayersOnPallet)
SELECT 1, 2, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 4;

-- an intermediate temp table used for processing
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#processing') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #processing;

-- let's populate the #processing table with duplicates
SELECT 
  idProduct, 
  Layers,
  LayersOnPallet,
  rCount = COUNT(*)
INTO #processing
FROM @tempTable
GROUP BY 
  idProduct, 
  Layers,
  LayersOnPallet
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

-- Remove the duplicates 
DELETE t 
FROM @TempTable t
JOIN  #processing p
  ON  p.idProduct      = t.idProduct 
  AND p.Layers         = t.Layers
  AND p.LayersOnPallet = t.LayersOnPallet

-- Add the new, updated record
INSERT @TempTable
SELECT  
  idProduct, 
  Layers * rCount,
  LayersOnPallet, 1
FROM #processing;

DROP TABLE #processing; -- cleanup

-- Final output
SELECT idProduct, Layers, LayersOnPallet, Summarized
FROM @TempTable;
```

Results:

```
idProduct   Layers      LayersOnPallet Summarized
----------- ----------- -------------- ----------
1           4           4              1
1           1           4              0
2           2           4              0
```